# Fastest way to retrieve unique record in MySQL: string vs float vs 2 ids

Tags: mysql, string, performance, floating-point, integer

I need to check if a particular record in a (potentially) large database (millions of records) exists.

I can choose to uniquely identify the record with:

- 2 integer numbers (example: 231321 and 312309)
- 1 float number (a combination of the two integer numbers. example: 231321.312309)
- 1 string (a combination of the two integer numbers. example: '231321@312309')

Is one of these three options better than the others?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 integers.

Rationale:

- Depending on actual integer range, you might not be able to store 2 integers
  in a single float without loss of precision.
- String is just a waste of space.
- For both float and string, you won't be able to index (and therefore search efficiently) on the second integer, if you ever need to.
- Also, there is a philosophical argument about [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and that violating it actually violates the 1st normal form.

Answer (score 0):

Well I wouldn't use the string just because it takes more space and is more data to compare. I don't think it will really matter which of the number options you choose. Just be sure to throw a UNIQUE INDEX on the field(s) and you should be good to go.